# spring data R2DBC change @Table dynamiclly or another strategy

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I have a problem about spring data R2DBC with sql server, I've used @Table annotation and a value of this is e.g. @Table("myschema.mytable") and this works well.
The problem is, when we move to another environment like prod, the database has another schema and, for security of this enterprise, I can't know the name of this schema, a recommendation was to create a properties and use it to get a name of schema.
Are there a way to change the value (or name) of @Table?
I know that exists DatabaseClient class and write a query but I think that this way is unsafe.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I never try on sql server, but the schema should not be on the @Table annotation, only the table name. The schema to use should usually be part of the database connection, which can be configured through properties

Comment: @Zinc can you please elaborate how to connect to a specific schema using R2DBC/MSSQL. The documentation is quite poor in that sense.